# Why is the expansion of $\arctan(x)$ a Taylor expansion, when its terms lack factorials in their denominators?

Tags: taylor-expansion

So as I started learning about Taylor series, I noticed that the $\arctan(x)$ expansion misses a factorial in the denominator. Since a Taylor series does have a factorial, I was wondering: how is the expansion of $\arctan(x)$ a Taylor expansion? Thanks in advance!

Also, how do I know how to choose alpha when calculating the expansion?

Comment: Multiply and divide by the factorial.

Comment: Hint:  $\frac{n!}{n!}=1$

Comment: You should write down the expansion you are talking about

Comment: The expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ around $0$ has no factorials either.

Comment: The Taylor series need not have a factorial: the derivative can cancel out the factorial in the formula. For instance, the Taylor expansion of $f(x)=1/(1-x)$ at $0$ is $1+x+x^2 + \dots$ because $f^{(n)}(0)=n!$.

Comment: The equation for finding a Taylor series from the function's derivatives involves a factorial. Writing out a particular Taylor series does not necessarily contain a factorial expression.

Comment: By the uniqueness  of expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor expansion is not a very particular expansion, but a method to derive such an expansion. But suppose $f(x)=\sum_k a_k(x-x_0)^k$ and everything is nice enough (so that we might pull the differential under the series). Then

$$ f^{(k)}(x_0) = k!a_k $$

So if such a form exists it nescessarily has to satisfy $a_k = f^{(k)}(x_0)/k!$.

Thus the characteristic of a taylor expansion is not having a $k!$ but being in terms of $x-x_0$.

So why do you not see $k!$ in your form? Remember that $\arctan^{(k)}$ has something like $k!$ as a factor. So after cancelling this out you remain with just something polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

$5$ does have factorial at the denominator because $$5=\frac{25200}{7!}$$

Comment: How do I choose alpha when calculating an expansion? Also, can anyone show me the proof of the taylor expansion for 1/(1-x) ?

Comment: @Beatrixx: I don't know what you call alpha.